# .Net core log Startup errors to app insights

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to log any startup errors but the logs are not flowing into application insights. I tried configuring app insights in program.cs but still I don't see any logs.

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>

    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.AddApplicationInsights();
            logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information);
        });
```

Comment: what logs are you expecting can you provide some example ?

Comment: I'm trying to see why app startup failed, any exceptions in main method or startup.cs

Answer (score 2):

By default it is not supported to handle exceptions from application startup, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-exceptions#web-api).

What I did to get the logs into the application insights is to add a try/catch block in the Main of Program.cs and initialize the TelemetryClient manually.

See the following code:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try 
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args)
                .Build().Run();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) 
        {
            TelemetryConfiguration telemetryConfiguration = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
            telemetryConfiguration.ConnectionString = "application-insights-connection-string";
            var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(telemetryConfiguration);
            telemetryClient.TrackException(ex);
            telemetryClient.Flush();
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Confirming this solution worked for me in my dotnet 7 project.

Answer (score 1):

For those using .NET 6 projects with minimal hosting model, this worked for me to capture the startup/shutdown messages into Application Insights:

```
// Program.cs

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
builder.Logging.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime", LogLevel.Information);

...
```

Answer (score 0):

To Capture logs from program.cs or startup.cs, you need to configure like this.

```
.ConfigureLogging((context, builder) =>
 {
   // Providing a connection string is required if need to capture logs during application startup, such as
   // in Program.cs or Startup.cs itself.
   builder.AddApplicationInsights(
       configureTelemetryConfiguration: (config) => config.ConnectionString = context.Configuration["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"],
       configureApplicationInsightsLoggerOptions: (options) => { }
      );

   // Capture all log-level entries from Program
   builder.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>(
                        typeof(Program).FullName, LogLevel.Trace);

  // Capture all log-level entries from Startup
  builder.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>(
                        typeof(Startup).FullName, LogLevel.Trace);
 });
```

Comment: This did not work for me.  I'm throwing a test exception in my Startup's Configure method, but I do not find any log in my App Insights.  Any clue what else it might be?  I'm using .NET 6.